# jquery error message

Tags: jquery

How can i show jquery error messages without using alert box? I simply need a one line error message to be shown in red on the screen.

Comment: You can put the message in a div and position it wherever you want it. CSS and DOM make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a function that does it...

```
function error(msg) {

  var msgBox = $('#msg-box');

  if (msgBox.length === 0) {
      msgBox = $('<div />', { 'id': 'msg-box'}).hide().prependTo('body');
  }

  msgBox.html(msg).fadeIn(500);

}
```

Then add some CSS

```
#msg-box {
   background: red;
   padding: 1em;
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/sqNMm/1/).

Comment: I would give you +1, if only for the fiddle, but even proposing to replace the native `alert` function? Uh....

Comment: @Felix Kling Sorry, it just sounded like that is what the OP wanted (I did leave the *not recommended* warning). I removed that part and hope to still get that +1 :)

Comment: @Felix Kling And that is why you are one of my fave Stackers!

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
function jAlert(text) {
    var jAl = $('#jAlert');
    jAl = jAl.length ? jAl : $('<div>',{'id':'jAlert'}).css({
        'padding': '10px',
        'border': '1px solid black',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'color': 'red'
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).appendTo('body').hide();


    jAl.html(text).show();
}
```

[fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Csv2V/)

if you only want to display debug information you could use console.log() in chrome or firebug

Comment: I would recommend placing the rules in a CSS stylesheet - otherwise you are mixing presentation and behaviour where it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes i just did it that way for the quick example, but you're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery UI's [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (also, [see here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)). Alternatively, you could just create a `p` or `div` element in-line with the rest of the content and put your message in that, providing a button to get rid of it (or you could hide it automatically after so many seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Put this where you want the errors to show up.

```
<div id='errorDiv'></div>
```

And put your error messages inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("<p>error message</p>").css("color", "red").appendTo($("body"));
```

You can also put an empty node (div) in the html, say with id "error_msg", then use this to add message into it:

```
$("#error_msg").html("error message");
```